# Hive: Extract string between first and last occurrence of a character

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table column which has string separated by '-' and i need to extract the string between first and last occurrence of '-'

```
    +-----------------+
    | col1            |
    +-----------------+
    | abc-123-na-00-sf|
    | 123-abc-01-sd   |
    | 123-abcd-sd     |  
    +-----------------+

    Required output:

    +-----------+
    | col1      |
    +-----------+
    | 123-na-00 |
    | abc-01    |
    | abcd      |  
    +-----------+
```

Please suggest some regex to extract the desired output.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with t as (select explode(array('abc-123-na-00-sf','123-abc-01-sd','123-abcd-sd')) as str)
select  regexp_extract (str,'-(.*)-',1)
from    t
;
```

---

```
123-na-00
abc-01
abcd
```

or

```
with t as (select explode(array('abc-123-na-00-sf','123-abc-01-sd','123-abcd-sd')) as str)
select  regexp_extract (str,'(?<=-).*(?=-)',0)
from    t
;
```

---

```
123-na-00
abc-01
abcd
```